# How to change TX power on my own esp32-beacon?

Tags: beacon, esp32, eddystone

I am emulating a beacon with ESP32, and i want to change TX power level to reach differents distances. how can i change TX power level?

This is for an asset tracking app and i am trying with differents hardware to see how the impact of hardware is on the system.

I've already tried with estimote beacons and with them I can change TX power level from -18dbm to 4dbm. But i haven't be able to do it with ESP32 chip.

I am doing this with Eddystone protocol, more specific Eddystone-UID.

```
EddystoneUid::EddystoneUid(const std::string& nid, const std::string& bid) {
    frame.len16bitServiceUuidPart = 0x03;   // <- 1 (data type value) + 2 (16-bit Eddystone UUID)
    frame.type16bitServiceUuid = 0x03;      // 16-bit Service UUID
    frame.eddystoneUuid = EDDYSTONE_SERVICE_UUID;
    frame.lenServiceDataPart = 0x17;        // Eddystone-UID full length (23bytes)
    frame.typeServiceData = 0x16;           // Service Data
    frame._eddystoneUuid = EDDYSTONE_SERVICE_UUID;
    frame.frameType = EDDYSTONE_FRAME_TYPE_UID;
    frame.ranging = 0x00;                   // TODO: ranging data
    memset(frame.nid, 0, sizeof(frame.nid));
    memset(frame.bid, 0, sizeof(frame.bid));
    memset(frame.rfu, 0, sizeof(frame.rfu));
    setBeaconId(nid, bid);
}
```

That example code shows the params needed to configure eddystone-uid frame, but I don't know how to change the TX power level.

in the line.

```
    frame.ranging = 0x00;                   // TODO: ranging data
```

This is to change de level of RSSI at 1 meter. in some docs it is called TX power level, but this isn't what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not think it is possible to alter the transmitter advertising power on the ESP32.

The esp_ble_adv_params_t structure is used to set the advertising parameters.  And while it lets you configure the advertising interval, and adjust channels, there is no documented way to change the strength of the transmission.

See details here:

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/bluetooth/esp_gap_ble.html

You are correct that some platforms do allow this.  It is common on Nordic NRF Bluetooth chipsets, and allowed by the Android  and Linux BlueZ platforms for supported chipsets.  But iOS and Mac do not allow this, either.

Comment: Hi David Greetings,Thanks for your answer.

 Yes i've been trying to find on docs, or google but I couldn't find anything about it. You confirm my suspicions. 

I would want to know about how to select the channel, advertising interval as well. and you answered, so thanks for that too.

I am using Rpi as well, with BlueZ and a nodejs library for bluetooth, could I do this with that library on rpi?

Answer (score 0):

you can change power levels, This blogger was closer to it: however the syntax is include there a

https://github.com/nkolban/esp32-snippets/issues/939

/* The power level can be one of:

- - ESP_PWR_LVL_N14
- - ESP_PWR_LVL_N11
- - ESP_PWR_LVL_N8
- - ESP_PWR_LVL_N5
- - ESP_PWR_LVL_N2
- - ESP_PWR_LVL_P1
- - ESP_PWR_LVL_P4
- - ESP_PWR_LVL_P7
    */